# In Python 3.4, how do I stop InsecureRequestWarning?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, urllib3

I see this message in my logfiles:

> /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:843:
>   InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding
>   certificate verification is strongly advised. See:
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

But look at my code; I am adding the indicated calls to stop these warnings:

```
# https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
...
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try: `logging.captureWarnings(False)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

I have had a situation where "urllib3.disable_warnings()" was not working but above one was.
Can't comment about the exact reason, but most probably it has something to do with the "requests" package versions